# Can Googleupdate.exe cause delays when shutting down in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, performance, shutdown

I have a computer running Windows XP which hangs in "windows is shutting down" for around two minutes. After running the Event Viewer, I've discovered that during this time, an error is recorded as a 10010 event. The Microsoft Help and Support Center gives the following details:

> Details
>
> Product: Windows Operating System
>
> ID: 10010
>
> Source: DCOM
>
> Version: 5.2
>
> Symbolic Name: EVENT_RPCSS_SERVER_START_TIMEOUT
>
> Message: The server %1 did not register with DCOM within the required timeout.
>
> Explanation 
>   The Component Object Model (COM) infrastructure tried to start the named server; however, the server did not reply within the required timeout period. There might be a deadlock, or the program might not have responded to the server initialization code within the timeout period of two minutes.

Going through the instructions to locate the program, I've found it referenced by a key: **application data/google/update/googleupdate.exe**

Is this behaviour typical of googleupdate.exe, or is there another cause?

Answer (score 0):

It happens often enough.  The following may help:
- Disable the Google Update Service:  Run services.msc, and look for Google Update Service.  You may find two of them, gupdate and gupdatem.  Double-click each and set the startup to Disabled, and then stop the services.

- Go to All Programs > Accessories > System Tools > Task Scheduler.  Look for Google update tasks in the schedule.  Disable or delete them.  (Chrome, Google Earth, and other Google software will usually put them back the next time they run, anyway.)
- In the registry, go to HKLM|Software|Microsoft|Windows|CurrentVersion|Run and make sure that there is no reference to the google update;  if there is, remove it.

This should stop Google Updater from running on its own, which would then keep it from running when you are trying to shut down.